# selenium - create xpath with span text which contains sup tag

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here is the HTML block from my code

```
<a href="#link" class='megamenu'>
 <span>
 "String1"
 <sup>®</sup>>
 "String2"
 </span>
 </a>
```

I want to create xpath which can validate text value in side span tag.

e.g. `//Span[text()='String1® String2']`

or `//Span[Conatains(text(),'String1® String2')]`

above xpath is not working because `<sup>` tag is used inside span. What text value I need to provide in Xpath to validate both string.

Comment: Try this xpath `/a[@href="#link"]/span/sup/text()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify span tag text try following xpath.

```
'//span[contains(.,"String1")][contains(.,"String2")][contains(.,"®")]'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by

> '//span[contains(.,'String1')[text()='String2']'

this will ignore sup